# gnuplot : anomalous behaviour of 'set xrange' in an animated 2D-plot of MD data

Tags: gnuplot

I am working on a Windows 7 machine using gnuplot 5 Patch level 1.

I am preparing an animation of the sequence of interatomic distances along a trajectory from a molecular dynamics calculation.

The following script works fine:

```
set termopt enhanced    # turn on enhanced text mode
# --- GRAPH a

set yrange [0.0:25.0]
set xlabel 't (fs)'
set ylabel "R_{ij} (A)"
set key box opaque

stats 'NeH2+_125K_TRAY171.DAT'

do for [i=1:STATS_records:2001] {
   plot 'NeH2+_125K_TRAY171.DAT' using ($1/10):2 every ::1::i with lines title 'R_{NeH_{1}}', \
        'NeH2+_125K_TRAY171.DAT' using ($1/10):3 every ::1::i with lines title 'R_{H_{1}H_{2}}',\
        'NeH2+_125K_TRAY171.DAT' using ($1/10):4 every ::1::i with lines title 'R_{NeH_{2}}',
}
```

## end of script

However the x-range is updated during the simulation and can be quite distracting since the data file is quite long.

To avoid updating the x-axis, I tried using the *set xrange* command

```
set xrange[0.0:7.0]
set yrange [0.0:25.0]
set xlabel 't (fs)'
...
```

When the animation starts, it works correctly but after plotting a few thousand data, it stops. Furthermore, there are no error messages in the console window of the aplication.

I have tested both scripts on a second windows 7 computer with gnuplot 5.2 and did observe the same behaviours.

Apparently the scripts are correct. Can anybody identify the problem?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that the `set yrange` also applies to the `stats` call (yes, the `yrange`, because you don't specify any column).

So in any case you might have less plot iterations than you expect. Try

```
reset
f = 'NeH2+_125K_TRAY171.DAT'
stats f

set xrange [0.0:7.0]
set yrange [0.0:25.0]
do for [i=1:STATS_records:2001] {
    plot f using ($1/10):2 every ::1::i title 'R_{NeH_{1}}', \
        '' using ($1/10):3 every ::1::i title 'R_{H_{1}H_{2}}',\
        '' using ($1/10):4 every ::1::i title 'R_{NeH_{2}}'
}
```

Comment: The code works fine now.  I did not realize that the scope of the stat commad affected the set xrange, set yrange. Besides the use of variables to refer to the filename simplifies the code. Thanks.